# No data displayed when using django ModelForm with Foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to display a django ModelForm in my template, but I could not get it to work.

Here is my code:

the template is this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}
{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
<section>       
    <article>
            <form action="{% url 'SaisirEnfant' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset>
                    <div id="newad"> {{ newenfant.as_p }} </div>                
                    <div id="sub"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </div>    
                </fieldset> 
            </form>     
    </article> 
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

and the models are like this:

```
class PersonneAdulte(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, verbose_name='Personne Adulte')
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    responsable = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('responsable'))

class Famille(models.Model):
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(PersonneAdulte, verbose_name='responsable')
    sous_responsable = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    coef_fam = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    id_fam = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Enfant(models.Model):
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(Famille, verbose_name='responsable')
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50 )
```

finaly the wiews is like this:

```
class PersonneAdulteForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PersonneAdulte
        exclude = ('profile')   

def PersonneAdulte(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        adulte = PersonneAdulteForm(request.POST)   
        if adulte.is_valid():    
            #creates a new `User`.
            new_user = UserenaSignup.objects.create_user(username=adulte.data['nom'],
                                                         email='nom.prenom@site.fr',
                                                         password='0000',
                                                         active=False,
                                                         send_email=False)                    
            # Send the signup complete signal
            userena_signals.signup_complete.send(sender=None,
                                                 user=new_user)
            #Activate a user with an activation key.
            activation_key = UserenaSignup.objects.get(user_id=new_user.id).activation_key
            user = UserenaSignup.objects.activate_user(activation_key)

            t = adulte.save(commit=False) 
            if t.responsable == False :   
                new_user.is_active = False
                new_user.save()
            else : 
                f = Famille.objects.create(pk=new_user.id, responsable_id=new_user.id, id_fam=new_user.id)

            p = adulte.save(commit=False)
            p.id = p.profile_id = new_user.id
            p.save()    

            return HttpResponse( 'id: ' + str(p.id)  )                                                                                                                                           
    else:
        adulte = PersonneAdulteForm()
    return render_to_response('familles/PersonneAdulte.html', dictionary={ 'adulte' : adulte}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Profile is the model defined by the userena package

My view is for creating a new `Enfant` instance but no data at all is displayed and there is no error message. The problem is related to the foreign key in my model (responsable) because if I exclude the field in my form it works fine. Anybody knows where this problem comes from or how I can debug it?

Comment: what data do you want to display? Also, how is your template defined ?

Comment: Does `responsable` have any data? What is the structure of it?

Comment: Need to see your template code as well.

Comment: I added the code in my question

Comment: I think I have found : the version 1.2.x userena that I use is not compatible with the 1.4.x version of django